# Converting screen coords to world coords

Tags: wpf, math, matrix, coordinates, transform

I'm working on a conversion matrix for a map application I'm currently writing.

I have a point in screen coordinates and the points in the target coordinate space, and for some stupid reason I cannot seem to figure out how to find the conversion matrix the converts the points in my screen coordinates to the world coordinates.

**For example:**

Coordinate (1005.758, 673.661) should be converted to (786382.6, 2961730.3)
and coordinate (1010.240, 665.217) should be converted to (786488.3, 2961837). I'm using WPF so that's why the screen coordinates are actually `double` and not `int`.

Comment: the data you gave us is not sufficient if you use a transform with translation (affine transformation) - check where (0,0) is mapped to and where (1,0) and (0,1) is pointed at and you can find everything you need here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_transformation - or post some more code and we might help you directly

Comment: I thought that two points in the different coordinate systems should be sufficient. I don't use translation - the scenario is that I get a WPF object that is actually a map and I get the two points in the different coordinate systems. The user can translate the WPF control (map) around but since the coordinates are relative to the canvas on which the map is sitting on the translation doesn't change the points.

Comment: if you don't use translation ((0,0) maps to (0,0)) than indeed two points are suffictient but the problem is rather simple (just a scale-transform) - in your case you just need to scale by 786382.6/1005.758 in the x-direction and 296173.3/673.661 in the y-direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With two coordinates you can extract scaling factor and translation (if the map is using these two operations only).

Scaling in the first dimension is given by

```
s1 = (786382.6 - 786488.3) / (1005.758 - 1010.24) => s1 ~ 23.583
```

and in the second via

```
s2 = (2961730.3 - 2961837) / (673.661 - 665.217) => s2 ~ -12.636
```

while the corresponding offsets are

```
o1 = 786382.6 - s1 * 1005.758 => o1 ~ 762663.586
```

and

```
o2 = 2961730.3 - s2 * 673.661 => o2 ~ 2970242.809
```

Thus your transformation is given by

```
(x, y) -> (o1+s1*x, o2+s2*y) = (762663.586+23.583*x, 2970242.809-12.636*y)
```

Comment: Awesome work Howard! Thanks for the quick and elegant solution!